# How .ko(elf format).strtab index decided?

Tags: linux, kernel, elf

I am curious .ko file .strtab information index decision mechanism.
Through some experiment, I know that the index is decided by symbol name.
As I think, it is calculated (hash, and so on) and sorted by calculated value.
I want to know exact algorithm, and mechanism of this.

※ When type readelf -s overlay.ko, then symbol is shown. And the each symbol has a index (actually symbol is shown sequentially by index). Attached picture file show overlay.ko index last part. I am curious this mechanism.
[overlay.ko index last part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szd3K.png)

Comment: Your question is exceedingly unclear. What index are you talking about, what  does `.strab` has to do with your question?

Answer (score 0):

ELF does not specify how string tables are constructed and ordered. Different ELF file producers make different choices there. Some implement tail merging (strings pointing into the middle of other strings), others do not. String table indices are not supposed to have meaning, so some implementation divergence here is completely fine.